# Uncaught ReferenceError: country2 is not defined

Tags: jquery, ajax

In this condition when I click button then Its showing

> error Uncaught ReferenceError: country2 is not defined.

Can you please help me to solve this error ?

```js
var country2 = document.getElementById("cntry1").value;
var state2 = document.getElementById("state1").value;

$.ajax({
      url: "ajax.php",
      type: "POST",
      data: {
        get_data: 'get_data',
        name: name,
        number: number,
        address: address,
        hobbies: hobbies,
        redio: redio,
        country12: country2,
        state12: state2
      },
      dataType: "text",
```

Comment: Where is your html ?

Comment: I feel its because country2 is getting its value

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please click the `<>` button and create a [mcve] - we need to see the HTML and where you are executing the code